# ORA-00933 Error message running reports with join in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run this report and when I do, it is only returning the tables and NOT the data inside the tables. What did I miss? Is my join incorrect?

````
Select person.First_Name, person.Last_Name, volunteer.VO_Person_ID, 
       skill.Skill_ID, interest.Interest_Description, 
       care_center.Care_Center_Name, care_center.Care_Center_Address,
       care_center.Nurse_In_Charge
from person, volunteer, skill, interest, care_center
where person.Person_id = volunteer.VO_Person_ID and interest.Interest_Description = 'Pediatrician';
Select person.First_Name, person.Last_Name, volunteer.VO_Person_ID, 
       skill.Skill_ID, interest.Interest_Description, 
       care_center.Care_Center_Name, care_center.Care_Center_Address,
       care_center.Nurse_In_Charge
from     person, volunteer, skill, interest, care_center
where   person.Person_id = volunteer.VO_Person_ID and interest.Interest_Description = 'Pediatrician'

From 
   CARE_CENTER c
   Join
   Volunteer_Assigned_Care_Center va
   On
   c.CareCenterID =va.CareCenterID
   Join
   VOLUNTEER v
   On va.VOLUNTEERId=
    v.VOLUNTEERId
    Join
    Interest i
     v.InterestId=i.InterestId;```
````

Comment: you have to `JOIN` all these tables `person, volunteer, skill, interest, care_center`.

Comment: Please share the output that you are getting. Also, You are missing joins between tables

Comment: @zealous how do I join? Do you mind showing me an example?

Comment: @DominiqueConnor go through this https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-inner-join/. Also provide your schema and expected result.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I changed the question to what I am getting now